# Overriding React bootstrap component styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have imported a `Table` component from `react-bootstrap` and want to use this in my project. However, I find it very difficult to override the default styling of this component. The only way I have figured out to do this is by adding `!important` to the end of every line, however I'm thinking there must be a better way.

This is what my Table component looks like:

```
<Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</Table>
```

And this is what my CSS file looks like:

```
th {
  text-align: center;
  border: none !important;
}
```

And without the !important it tries to keep the border (one of many cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how pre-styled component libraries work; they usually have a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for css than just a single layer like you have.  A pseudo example would be:

```
table {
  thead {
    tr {
      th {
        border: 1 px solid black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which outranks your single nested css target.  `!important` should only be used when absolutely necessary (IMO).  Another option is to write your own, equally specific css and use that to override what `react-bootstrap` provides.  It's just a price you pay for using libraries like that.